# ADVERTENCIA System.ObsoleteAttribute está definido en varios ensamblados del alias global

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Al intentar compilar me sale un mensaje de advertencia, favor si me indican porque sale este mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]